# iOS 9 and iOS 10 CoreData simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have a question about Swift 3 releted with Core Data. I am developing an App in Swift with Xcode 8, and I need to support iOS 9 and iOS10. The problem is that I don't know how to get the AppDelegate and the Context (to use for store and get data from my Entities). I think my code should be something like this:

```
#if avaliable(iOS10,*)
{
     // iOS 10 code
} else
{
    // iOS 9 code
}
```

But I don't know what to do.

Any idea?

(A small help in correction would be appreciated)

Comment: Why do you think "get the AppDelegate and the Context" has to be handled differently in iOS 9 and 10?

Comment: @Josep ask yourself whether core data behaves differently between iOS 9 & 10. Then ask yourself the exact reason why you need to differentiate. Then update your OP. For example, I have three apps that span iOS 6 to 10.2 with no difference in core data implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**# Code in Swift 3 for Core Data for both iOS 9 and iOS 10 #**

Since you want the core data code for both iOS 9 and iOS 10 then you don't have to use `NSPersistentContainer` as it not supported in iOS 9, so you have to use old method instead

If at the time of project creation you haven't included core data and later you want to include it, follow the following steps :-

**Step 1.** Go to `Build Phases` -> `Link Binary with Library` -> `click on + sign` -> `Add CoreData.framework`
[image]

**Step 2.** Now got to `file -> New File -> select Data Model`.

**Step 3.** Now you need to write some code inside `AppDelegate.swift` to get set go :-

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch. 
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        self.saveContext()

    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "hacker.at.work.mTirgger" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Model", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject?
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject?

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**That's all your Core Data is ready for both iOS 9 and iOS 10 in Swift 3. Enjoy !!!**

Comment: Why instead of this not using the new iOS 10 stack for iOS 10

Comment: Some projects come with compatibility for both ios 9 & 10 as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support iOS9 then the best bet is not to use any new iOS10 stuff.

Stick with the iOS9 API for now, and in the future when you eventually drop iOS9 support you can refactor your code to use the newer methods then.

edit: Just to be clear, all the iOS9 code will run fine on iOS10. You don't need to do anything special there, it is all backwards compatible.

Comment: I've downloaded Xcode 7 again (the latest version before September's Xcode8)

I have created a new project based on the Master-Detail template. I have not changed anything.

I have opened the project with Xcode 8.2.1, the editor has updated it, and has begun to give errors that I can not correct.

Comment: Please create a new question for your issue, comments is not the correct place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

**CoreData for iOS9 and iOS10 simultaneously**

For who you may need it:

This is an unmodified Master-Detail App template from the latest Xcode7 (for iOS9) release of May 2016. I have updated it with the current latest Xcode (Version 8.2.1)

With this template you can develope an application that uses CoreData compatible with iOS9 and iOS10, at least for now (May 2017)

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  trash
//
//  Created by Markus on 22/05/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Markus. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem
    splitViewController.delegate = self

    let masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
    let controller = masterNavigationController.topViewController as! MasterViewController
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Split view

func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController:UIViewController, onto primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> Bool {
    guard let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController else { return false }
    guard let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? DetailViewController else { return false }
    if topAsDetailController.detailItem == nil {
        // Return true to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
        return true
    }
    return false
}
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.senbei.trash" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "trash", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject?
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject?

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}

}
```

**MasterViewController.swift**

```
//
//  MasterViewController.swift
//  trash
//
//  Created by Markus on 22/05/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Markus. All rights reserved.
//


import UIKit
import CoreData

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem

    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(insertNewObject(_:)))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    if let split = self.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = self.splitViewController!.isCollapsed
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func insertNewObject(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
    let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: entity.name!, into: context)

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    newManagedObject.setValue(Date(), forKey: "timeStamp")

    // Save the context.
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }
}

// MARK: - Segues

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let object = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Table View

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
    self.configureCell(cell, withObject: object)
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        context.delete(self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as! NSManagedObject)

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}

func configureCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell, withObject object: NSManagedObject) {
    //cell.textLabel!.text = object.value(forKey: "timeStamp")!.description
    cell.textLabel!.text = (object.value(forKey: "timeStamp")! as AnyObject).description
}

// MARK: - Fetched results controller

//var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    //let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

    //let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Event>(entityName: "Event") //another alternative

    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Event")


    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Event", in: self.managedObjectContext!)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    do {
        try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
    } catch {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
         //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
         abort()
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}
//var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>?

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
        case .insert:
            self.tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
        case .delete:
            self.tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
        default:
            return
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .update:
            self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!, withObject: anObject as! NSManagedObject)
        case .move:
            tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}

/*
 // Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed.

 func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
     // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
     self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
 */

}
```

**DetailViewController.swift**

```
//
//  DetailViewController.swift
//  trash
//
//  Created by Markus on 22/05/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Markus. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!


var detailItem: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        self.configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let detail = self.detailItem {
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
            //label.text = detail.value(forKey: "timeStamp")!.description
            label.text = (detail.value(forKey: "timeStamp")! as AnyObject).description
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.configureView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

**Data model is the original from template, as well as storyboard. Both there are not modified.**
[image: Data model screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new API and get the benefits out of it by doing something like this:

```
var coreDataManager: CoreDataManagerProtocol!
#if available(iOS10,*)
{
    coreDataManager = CoreDataManagerNewStack()
} else
{
    coreDataManager = CoreDataManagerOldStack()
}
```

and then you implement the new CoreData with the new stack into a class:

```
class CoreDataManagerNewStack: CoreDataManagerProtocol {
    var container: NSPersistentContainer
    // etc
}
```

and the old one with the code paster above with the whole code to generate the stack

```
class CoreDataManagerOldStack: CoreDataManagerProtocol {
     lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()
    // etc
}
```