# Core data app with Xcode 9

Tags: core-data

I want to create an core data app with Xcode 9 that support iOS 9 as well. How to do that because default CoreData setup comes with method that are introduced in iOS 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 9 and iOS 10 CoreData simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651239/ios-9-and-ios-10-coredata-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove default CoreData setup, then Maybe you must add setup method to create context,model, coordinator and so on.